# using react js to create a website that could read .csv file and show in chartjs

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, read.csv

I try this but keep getting this error "Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas can be reused.", even I used destroy also not working.

I was trying read .csv file by using react.js and display by using chart.js.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2'
import * as d3 from 'd3'
//import { csv } from 'd3'

const BarChart1 = () => {
  let myChart;
    let filename = 'drug-abusers-by-gender.csv';
    d3.csv(filename, function(loadedData) {
        //console.log(loadedData);

        let data = [];
        let labels = [];

        for (let i=1; i < loadedData.length; i++) {
            console.log(loadedData[i]);

            let year = loadedData[i].year;
            labels.push(year);

            let num = loadedData[i].no_of_drug_abusers;
            data.push(num);
            //console.log(num);
        }

        let options = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    data: data,
                    fill: false,
                    pointRadius: 0,
                    pointHoverRadius: 0,
                    borderColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                }]
            }
        };

        //myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('BarChart1'), options);
    })

    return (
        <canvas id="BarChart1" ></canvas>
      );
}

export default BarChart1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been running into this too. First I upgraded to the latest version of Chart.js and that didn't fix it but it did provide the "remove()" function to delete the canvas.

What I've done to get past it is first delete the canvas:

```
<div id="fullReport1">
    <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
</div>
```

and then create a new canvas like so and use jQuery to append it to the div I have the canvas in:

```
var old_canvas = $('#myChart1');
if(old_canvas) old_canvas.remove();

var newCanvas = $('<canvas/>',{
                   'class':'chart1',
                    id: 'myChart1'                   
                });
$('#fullReport1').append(newCanvas);
```

After that I create the chart and fill the canvas.

(I don't recall for sure where I found that solution so someone else here deserves the credit because I think I did find it here on stackoverflow)

Comment: so it means i need to add the jQuery inside for it to run?

Comment: Well, that basically the logic I used.

The "old_canvas.remove();" line is a charts.js feature in the latest version. I'm not familiar with React.js but there may be ways to use it to get a reference to the canvas to delete it and append a new canvas with the same name with React or plain JS.